# Remove non-alphabetic characters but keep rational numbers

Tags: regex

I have this example string:

```
24bit 88.2kHz 5.1 (Surround Free Lossless Audio Codec).
```

I would like to remove all non-alphabetic chars *including* the dot that ends a sentence BUT want to keep a rational number - so the result should be:

```
24bit 88.2kHz 5.1 Surround Free Lossless Audio Codec
```

Comment: what regex engine/programming language/tool do you have? does it support BRE? ERE? PCRE?

Comment: Does all your strings look like this one? Could you please provide an example list of strings your trying to match.

Comment: Can your input contain the notation `.5` for `0.5`?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
(?<!\d)\.|\.+$|[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC7xO1/2)

Comment: a little problem, `(?<=\d)[.](?!\d)` could be left there. like `.... codec2.` or `... 5.1.`  but it might be ok for OP.

Comment: @Kent You're right. Is it possible somehow to fix it ? Because I have no idea. :(

Comment: `(?<=\d)\.(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\.|[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]`?

Comment: Bigger issue is that we don't even know if lookbehind is supported in OP's regex platform.

Comment: @anubhava yo, that's why I posted a comment under the Q instead of answer..:-D

Comment: @Kent What about `(?<!\d)\.|\.+$|[^a-z0-9. ]` ?

Comment: @hsz it should be fine too. assume `5.` won't be in the middle.  and it shouldn't be. :)

Comment: @Kent thank you. this worked. Thank you all i bet they are all good as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 .]
```

Comment: you forget to exclude ending dot. Try `[^a-zA-Z0-9 .]|\.$`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# you could use:

```
[\p{M}\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}-[.\r\n]]|(?<!\d)\.
```

---

If you use Java:

```
[\p{M}\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}&&[^.\r\n]]|(?<!\d)\.
```